# vue.js vuetify: v-parallax doesn't work with local files?

Tags: image, vue.js, parallax, vuetify.js, src

Using `v-parallax` with an online image source like this works fine:

```html
<v-parallax 
    dark 
    height="470" 
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466916932233-c1b9c82e71c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80">
</v-parallax>
```

But using it with a local asset `src="@/assets/img/my-picture.png"` doesn't work.

The same goes for `<v-img src="my/local/source>`, whereby `<img>` works fine.

What is the way to make it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this `:src="require('@/assets/img/my-picture.png')"`

Comment: Still the case, any explanation for why this is needed?